# How to position a div above another div without cutting the top div off

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling with trying to achieve the attached layout. I am trying to get my pop-up card to sit above the background div but the content is being cut off where the background div ends.

Your help is very much appreciated :) [`About Me Desired Layout`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxWL8.png)

```css
/*About Me Section*/

.about-me {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 10%;
 height: 500px;
 margin-top: -7%;
 z-index: -1;
 background-color: #E5460E;
 clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 -100%);
}

.about-card {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 0;
 margin: 0auto;
 z-index: 1000000;
 width: 80%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="about-me">
  <div class="about-card">
   <div class="story">
   <div class="story-photo">
    <img class="story-me" src="About-Me.png">
   </div>
    <h3 class="story-title">My Story</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget lobortis orci. Vivamus iaculis lobortis dolor. Suspendisse ultricies nulla et ex aliquam laoreet. Donec nunc risus, posuere interdum efficitur id, dignissim eget enim. Duis bibendum ipsum eu malesuada porta.
    <br>
    Vivamus non neque orci. Aenean varius dolor posuere est fermentum porttitor. Maecenas id porttitor felis. Morbi facilisis, dui in semper consequat, nulla dolor semper massa, ac vehicula felis tortor nec eros. Sed quis ante eu diam efficitur laoreet.
    </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</body>
```

Comment: `clip-path` is doing that.

Comment: Thanks for including the desired layout image! Many users forget to provide this valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your content div (`.about-card`) is within the `.about-me` div and is getting cut off by the `clip-path` in your CSS. Make a separate div within `.about-me` called `.about-me-background` and give it the styling instead:

```css
/*About Me Section*/

.about-me-background {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 10%;
 height: 500px;
 margin-top: -7%;
 z-index: -1;
 background-color: #E5460E;
 clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 0 -100%);
}

.about-card {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 0;
 margin: 0auto;
 z-index: 1000000;
 width: 80%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="about-me">
  <div class="about-me-background">
  </div>
  <div class="about-card">
   <div class="story">
   <div class="story-photo">
    <img class="story-me" src="About-Me.png">
   </div>
    <h3 class="story-title">My Story</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget lobortis orci. Vivamus iaculis lobortis dolor. Suspendisse ultricies nulla et ex aliquam laoreet. Donec nunc risus, posuere interdum efficitur id, dignissim eget enim. Duis bibendum ipsum eu malesuada porta.
    <br>
    Vivamus non neque orci. Aenean varius dolor posuere est fermentum porttitor. Maecenas id porttitor felis. Morbi facilisis, dui in semper consequat, nulla dolor semper massa, ac vehicula felis tortor nec eros. Sed quis ante eu diam efficitur laoreet.
    </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</body>
```

Now you will see that `.about-card` extends below the red background.

Answer (score 0):

Dude! Try to make it simple by using the structure which follows header, footer, sections, etc. and develop your code.
try this snippet and hope this works well for you!.

```
body{
margin:auto;
}

header{ 
height: 70%;
width: 100%;
background:red;
}

footer{
height: 30%;
width: 100%;
position:absolute;
background:#fff;
}

#insidebox{ /*align your css based on your requirement*/
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
z-index: 15;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -100px 0 0 -150px; /* adjust accordingly */
background: red;
border:1px solid;
background:white;  
}

.rotateCSS{
/*css goes here for rorating the text*/
}

<body>
<header>
<section id="rotateCSS">
<div> About Me </div>
</section>
</header>
<footer>
<section>
</section>
</footer>

<section id="insidebox">
<div>
    hello for box in center
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, I put the HTML as ...

```
<div class="about">
    <p>ABOUT ME</p>
</div>
<div class="about__content">
    ...
</div>
```

then use `position: absolute` to lay over

Hope to be helpful to you, bro

-

just a demo: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/chienweiluo/pen/wqVKmZ?editors=1100)

Comment: This doesn't look like the image the asker attached. It looks like they want the white content div to be half over the red and half not.

Comment: https://s.codepen.io/chienweiluo/debug/EvqZoZ/vWkRwnLbdLZM

hope this can get the point